# PostgreSQL List of Transactions

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions

Is there a list of transactions that I can see that have not been committed yet?

Example:

```
Begin;
delete
from table
where column IS NOT NULL;
```

I have not committed this yet. I would like to see this and every other transaction taking place that has not been committed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the list of database session that have an open transaction along with the transaction ID in `pg_stat_activity`:

```
SELECT pid, backend_xid
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE backend_xid IS NOT NULL;
```

You don't say what you want that information for ...